# Programmatically push a NavigationLink in iOS16

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the previous iOS versions, I programmatically pushed a NavigationLink with

```
NavigationLink(isActive: $searched, destination: { SearchView(originalSearchPhrase: $searchedPhrase) }, label: {})
```

and toggling the isActive variable when I wanted it to be pushed. However, in iOS16, all of the NavigationLinks with isActive are deprecated. Is there still a way to push NavigationLinks programmatically?

Comment: Yes there is, may I suggest you read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Migrating-to-New-Navigation-Types and/or watch this [wwdc video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10054)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We just need to push corresponding link value into `NavigationStack` path.

[image: demo]

Here is main part. Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

```
    enum Dest: Hashable {
        case search, details
    }

  @State private var path: [Dest] = []

  var body: some View {
     NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        Button("Go search") { path.append(.search) }  // << here !!
        Divider()
        NavigationLink(value: Dest.search) {
            Text("Search")
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Dest.self) {
            switch $0 {
            case .search:
                Text("Search Destination Here")
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/iOS16/TestNavigationStackPush.swift)