# How do you emulate old List selection + NavigationLink behavior with navigationDestination?

Tags: swiftui

The old way works, even with the new `NavigationStack`.

```swift
@SceneStorage("selection") private var selection: Int?

var body: some View {
  NavigationStack {
    List(1..<10, selection: $selection) { selection in
      NavigationLink("\(selection)") {
        Text("\(selection)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Replace what's in the `NavigationStack` with this, though, and the views don't get pushed.

```swift
List(1..<10, selection: $selection) { selection in
  NavigationLink("\(selection)", value: selection)
}
.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) {
  Text("\($0)")
}
```

Get rid of the `selection` argument, and turn that line into the following? Then the views do get pushed, but of course, the selection won't be bound to whatever else you need it for (scene storage, here).

```swift
List(1..<10) { selection in
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in SwiftUI under iOS 16. It works fine on macOS Ventura.

I've resorted to this horrible workaround that only does selection (not deselection), but is still better that nothing:

```
.navigationDestination(for: SomeObject.self) { item in
    let _ =  Task {
        self.selection = item // set selection here
    }
    SomeDetailView()
}
```

I've reported the bug to Apple, but since SwiftUI releases are tied to OS releases, there probably won't be a clean solution for another year or so.

Comment: the original question seems to be buggy in ventura for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why would you need that exactly in List (highlighting works anyway), but probably you wanted this

```
List(1..<10) { selection in
  NavigationLink("\(selection)", value: selection)
}
.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { item in
  Text("\(item)")
    .onAppear { selection = item }
}
```

or even (again probably) you just needed `path` of `NavigationStack(path:` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586530/12299030

Comment: `onAppear` doesn't have the right semantics, even if it does "work". `path` doesn't work with `SceneStorage` and doesn't represent one-level deep.